# Inserting characters in a string at various points

Tags: insert, substring

Let me preface this by saying that I am not a coder, and everything I do know is self taught, I can look up things and copy and paste commands substituting my values but I cannot code from scratch, and complicated functions are way above me, so go easy with me, lol

I have a table that has these values in a field

gallery/category_123/gallery_22_123_6165.jpg

gallery/category_39/gallery_22_39_32640.jpg

I need to add a new field that takes those values and inserts a tn_ after the second slash, which is not always in the same character position, either forward or backward.  So the new field would contain these values

gallery/category_123/tn_gallery_22_123_6165.jpg

gallery/category_39/tn_gallery_22_39_32640.jpg

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Uh... You actually have to upload the images for us to see...

Comment: Which programming language is preferred for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

here is another possible solution. You can pass the string.replace function a function to determine what the replacement value should be. The function will be passed three arguments. The first argument is the matching text, the second argument is the position within the original string, and the third argument is the original string.

The following example will replace the second "L" in "HELLO, WORLD" with "M".

```
var s = "HELLO, WORLD!";
var nth = 0;
s = s.replace(/L/g, function (match, i, original) {
    nth++;
    return (nth === 2) ? "M" : match;
});
```